# NSDate in specific format

Tags: iphone, compare, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How do I get Todays date in "April 27" this format and compare with same string in iphone sdk.

Comment: Yes I done this with:NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LLLL d"]; NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

Answer (score 1):

By using [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).